# How can I find the bounds of a google map route?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, bounds

I'm creating a route in Google maps with a data object I have stored:

```
        routeData = {
            origin: 'address A',
            destination: 'address B',
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
            waypoints: [obj, obj, obj],
            optimizeWaypoints: false
        };
```

Because I have other objects on this map as well, I have set `optimizeWaypoints: false`.

Then I draw the route using this code:

```
        // Instantiate a directions service.
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

        // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
            preserveViewport: true,
            suppressMarkers: true,
            map: map
        });

        directionsService.route(routeData, function(result, status) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
        });
```

`directionsDisplay` is a global variable.

When all objects has been drawn on the map, I go through them all to get the bounds.

```
fitMapObjectBounds: function(mapData){
    var bounds          = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var marker, circle, route  = null;
    var fitTheBounds    = false;

    // Marker
    $(mapData.markers).each(function(key, value){
        marker = new google.maps.Marker(value);
        bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
        fitTheBounds = true;
    });

    // Circles
    $(mapData.circles).each(function(key, value){
        circle = new google.maps.Circle(value);
        bounds.union(circle.getBounds());
        fitTheBounds = true;
    });

    if(fitTheBounds == true) {
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }

}
```

My question is, how do I get the bounds of my route? I can't really find a good example of this.

**UPDATE**
So I have added this code in my `fitMapObjectBounds` functions, but it's not working:

```
directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
directionsService.route(mapData.routeStreet, function(result, status) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    bounds.union(directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].bounds);
});
```

Comment: Best would be if you can create a JSFiddle with full/working code that we can test. But why do you actually create `new google.maps.XXXX` in your `each` loops? Is every marker/circle/other object not already created and stored anywhere?

Comment: We have 3 different maps (3 different views). One for readers (frontend), one for editors when working on text and one where editors can work with the map. We store only JSON data and not the entire object.

Comment: Why not store the directions route(s) to a global variable that you can reuse in your `fitMapObjectBounds` function?

Comment: Why on earth do this Q get downvoted? It's a legit question!

Comment: How much are you willing to pay for an upvote? Just kidding... but you'll never know, unless the person who downvoted it tells you why... ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounds of the route displayed by default (the first one returned) is

```
directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].bounds
```

[documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsRoute)

**code snippet:**

```js
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var routeData = {
    origin: 'New York, NY',
    destination: 'Philadelphia, PA',
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
    waypoints: [],
    optimizeWaypoints: false
  };
  // Instantiate a directions service.
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;

  // Create a renderer for directions and bind it to the map.
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    preserveViewport: true,
    suppressMarkers: true,
    map: map
  });

  directionsService.route(routeData, function(result, status) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(result);
    map.fitBounds(directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].bounds);
  });
  // fitObjectBounds()
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: That's great. But how can I use `directionsDisplay.getDirections().routes[0].bounds` in my `fitMapObjectBounds()` function without having to redraw the route?

Comment: Keep a reference to each `directionsDisplay` object (one for each route) or keep the results of each result from the `directionsService (it has the bounds in it). Please add a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question if you are having issues doing that.